# Deploying shared server controls with web.config transforms

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, teamcity, webdeploy

I'm using `teamcity` to deploy our web application to several servers using `msbuild` and `webdeploy`.

I have a configuration per customer / environment combination - for example:

```
Internal-Dev
Customer1-Test
Customer1-Pilot
Customer1-Live
Customer2-Test
Customer2-Pilot
Customer2-Live
```

I only need these configurations so that the deployment process can use web.config transformations to set the appropriate connection strings and other settings for the installation.

The problem that I have is that I have a shared web server controls project which really only needs two configurations - `debug` and `release` - but I need to copy all the above configurations into this project in order to get them to work.  If I delete `Customer2-Pilot` from the shared project, I can't deploy to customer 2's pilot server because it is looking for the `Customer2-Pilot` configuration for the shared project which doesn't exist.

Currently, I copy the application's configuration names into the shared project but that is impractical as we have several applications each going to different customers so the shared project could get dozens of configurations which are all copies of `Release` or `Debug`

I would like to be able to configure the build system so that I can say that the `Internal-Dev` configuration of the web application project uses the shared project's `Debug` configuration and all the other configurations use the shared project's `Release` configuration.  This is possible from within the IDE, using the configuration manager which can tie a solution configuration to individual project configurations but I'm not sure how to do this from within `teamcity`.

My current teamcity configuration is using the `MSBuild` runner with the web application's **project** file as the build file path and the configuration parameters set to deploy it to the relevant server with the correct configuration after it has been built.  The shared project is in a sub-repository of the web application repository so it is fetched and built automatically.

Is there any way that I can change this set up to get what I want?  Do I need to change the build file path to be the solution instead of the project so that I can use the configuration manager settings to configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is as simple as changing the **build file path** parameter to be the solution file instead of the project file.  This means that you specify a **solution** configuration instead of a **project** configuration.  Solution configurations are managed in the configuration manager and you can specify the configuration of each project in the solution configuration so it all works nicely.

I have two projects that need to be published (a web application and a WCF service application) and they depend upon five other class library projects.  I have it set up so that the class library projects are built using either the **Debug** or **Release** configurations and the two projects that have config files that need to be transformed have one configuration per system.

One thing of note.  In the old set up I had to have two build steps - one to build and deploy the web application and one to build and deploy the WCF service application.  When I use the solution file as the build file, I don't need two steps any more as they are both part of the solution and so they both get built and deployed.